# Lamp stack running on google cloud and want to create a replica database

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, lamp

I have to set the `mysql server..... log_bin=ON`.
I have managed to set the server_id and gtid_mode. I've read some documentation on mysql site.

However cant resolve this is the error.

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL log_bin=ON ;
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'log_bin' is a read only variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running MySQL inside a Compute Engine instance or are you using [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql)? Changing the log_bin variable is currently [not supported in Cloud SQL for MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#mysql-l) (log_bin is not listed as a supported flag) and while [a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110941509) to allow users to change this flag's value was submitted a while ago, changes don't appear to have been implemented as of yet.

If you're running MySQL inside a Compute Engine instance, I would suggest trying to declare --log-bin [as a startup option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin) instead.